# c++ shared_ptr in polymorphism without virtual destructor

Tags: c++, polymorphism, factory

A typical factory design pattern require the base class to declare virtual destructor, but this can be actually avoided using `shared_ptr`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

class Dog {
  public:
  ~Dog() { cout << "dog destroyed\n"; }
};

class Yellowdog : public Dog {
  public:
  ~Yellowdog() { cout << "Yellow dog destroyed.\n"; }
};

class DogFactory {
  public:
  static shared_ptr<Dog> createYellowdog() { 
    return shared_ptr<Yellowdog>(new Yellowdog()); 
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  auto ptr = DogFactory::createYellowdog();
  cout << ptr.use_count() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In this case the output is `yellowdog destroyed` followed by `dog destroyed`. But why? Why using `shared_ptr` can omit the virtual keyword before `~Dog`?

Comment: Because of the `Deleter` which is copied/transferred with the pointer.

Comment: Because `shared_ptr` is magic. :-S

Comment: To be more clear, the `Deleter` does something similar to `delete (Yellowdog*) p;`. You will get UB with `return shared_ptr<Dog>(new Yellowdog());` though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because `shared_ptr` stores type-erased deleter in the control block, which is created when the first `shared_ptr` is created. In your case `shared_ptr` is created for yellow dog, and deleter is to call yellow-dog destructor.

When you copy (or copy-construct) one `shared_ptr` to another, they *share* the same control block, and new shared ptr is going to call deleter from the original one - the one which will call yellowdog destructor.

However, it doesn't really make the class polymorphic and suitable for factory implementation - any other non-virtual function in the class will be called based on static type of `shared_ptr`, and you do not want this in polymorphic classes.

Answer (score 1):

What SergeyA says is totally correct, for those who want to see the real code,
here is the shared_ptr implementation from LLVM (I only show part of the code which are relevant for explaination):

```
template<class _Tp>
class _LIBCPP_SHARED_PTR_TRIVIAL_ABI _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS shared_ptr
{
    //Constructor taking a pointer
    template<class _Yp, class = _EnableIf<
        _And<__compatible_with<_Yp, _Tp>>::value> 
    >
    explicit shared_ptr(_Yp* __p) : __ptr_(__p) {
        unique_ptr<_Yp> __hold(__p);
        typedef typename __shared_ptr_default_allocator<_Yp>::type _AllocT;
        typedef __shared_ptr_pointer<_Yp*, __shared_ptr_default_delete<_Tp, _Yp>, _AllocT > _CntrlBlk;
        __cntrl_ = new _CntrlBlk(__p, __shared_ptr_default_delete<_Tp, _Yp>(), _AllocT());
        __hold.release();
        __enable_weak_this(__p, __p);
    }
...
//other code omited
}

//Move Constructor
template<class _Tp>
template<class _Yp>
inline
shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(shared_ptr<_Yp>&& __r,
                            typename enable_if<__compatible_with<_Yp, element_type>::value, __nat>::type)
         _NOEXCEPT
    : __ptr_(__r.__ptr_),
      __cntrl_(__r.__cntrl_)
{
    __r.__ptr_ = nullptr;
    __r.__cntrl_ = nullptr;
}
```

Step 1:
when you call `shared_ptr<Yellowdog>(new Yellowdog());`, first the constructor taking pointer will be called, _Tp is same as _Yp in this case. There a control block is also created, taking _Yp* (so Yellowdog*) as input, and saves it inside. Then the created control block is saved as its virtual interface (type-erased) inside shared_ptr

Step 2:
Then during function return `shared_ptr<Yellowdog>` is converted to `shared_ptr<Dog>`.
In this case, the move constructor of `shared_ptr<Dog>` is called, however, this time _Tp is Dog, _Yp is Yellowdog. so a implicit conversion from Yellowdog* to Dog* is happening for `__ptr_`. But for `__ctrl_` it is a simple copy, nothing changes.

Step 3:
During destruction, the deallocator from `__ctrl_` will get called, and since it has saved Yellowdog* from the begining, it can call its destructor directly, and in turn it calls its parent (Dog) destructor.
Therefore no virtual destructor is needed for Dog in this case.